MySQL 8 Replication Master-Master fatal error
I have two servers with the same MySQL 8.0.40. I set up a Master to Master replication.
When I run the command SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G; on both servers, I see an error: The replica I/O thread stops because source and replica have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on replica but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
This does not make sense to me because the results of the query in both servers show that they have different server-ids.
Below is my mysql.cnf for both severs and the results of the query too:
mysql.cnf Server 1:
[mysqld]
#MySQL replication settings.
server-id=1
log_bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=row
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=1
replicate-do-db=testdb
replicate-ignore-table=testdb.products
replicate-ignore-table=testdb.notifications

mysql.cnf Server 2:
[mysqld]
#MySQL replication settings.
server-id=2
log_bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=row
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2
replicate-do-db=testdb
replicate-ignore-table=testdb.products
replicate-ignore-table=testdb.notifications
#MySQL other settings.

Query result Server 1:
mysql> SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Replica_IO_State: 
                  Source_Host: 192.168.0.2
                  Source_User: replicator
                  Source_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Source_Log_Pos: 17537818
               Relay_Log_File: ns105771-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
           Replica_IO_Running: No
          Replica_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: testdb
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: testdb.notifications,testdb.products
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Source_Log_Pos: 17537818
              Relay_Log_Space: 339
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Source_SSL_Allowed: No
           Source_SSL_CA_File: 
           Source_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Source_SSL_Cert: 
            Source_SSL_Cipher: 
               Source_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Source: NULL
Source_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 13117
                Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The replica I/O thread stops because source and replica have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on replica but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Source_Server_Id: 1
                  Source_UUID: 
             Source_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
    Replica_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Source_Retry_Count: 10
                  Source_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 240913 15:12:17
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Source_SSL_Crl: 
           Source_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Source_TLS_Version: 
       Source_public_key_path: public_key.pem
        Get_Source_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

Query result server 2:
mysql> SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Replica_IO_State: 
                  Source_Host: 192.168.0.3
                  Source_User: replicator
                  Source_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Source_Log_Pos: 17606972
               Relay_Log_File: ns105772-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
           Replica_IO_Running: No
          Replica_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: testdb
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: testdb.notifications,testdb.products
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Source_Log_Pos: 17606972
              Relay_Log_Space: 339
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Source_SSL_Allowed: No
           Source_SSL_CA_File: 
           Source_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Source_SSL_Cert: 
            Source_SSL_Cipher: 
               Source_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Source: NULL
Source_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 13117
                Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The replica I/O thread stops because source and replica have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on replica but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Source_Server_Id: 2
                  Source_UUID: 
             Source_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
    Replica_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Source_Retry_Count: 10
                  Source_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 240913 15:12:37
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Source_SSL_Crl: 
           Source_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Source_TLS_Version: 
       Source_public_key_path: public_key.pem
        Get_Source_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

Both replicas were created and started as below:
    CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO
        SOURCE_HOST='IP Server 1',
        SOURCE_USER='replicator',
        SOURCE_PASSWORD='password',
        SOURCE_LOG_FILE='SOURCE_LOG_FILE_SERVER_2',
        SOURCE_LOG_POS=SOURCE_LOG_POS_SERVER_2,
        SOURCE_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH='public_key.pem';
    START REPLICA;

CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO
        SOURCE_HOST='IP Server 2',
        SOURCE_USER='replicator',
        SOURCE_PASSWORD='password',
        SOURCE_LOG_FILE='SOURCE_LOG_FILE_SERVER_1',
        SOURCE_LOG_POS=SOURCE_LOG_POS_SERVER_1,
        SOURCE_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH='public_key.pem';
    START REPLICA;

I restarted MySQL with no results. Replica_IO_Running still shows No

This might be a bug in MySQL 8.0

Have you checked the databases directly to confirm they have different server_id's and server_uuids select @@global.server_id, @@global.server_uuid; ?

I solved my issue. When you do Source to Source replication, you have to be careful what IP to use. This query CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO SOURCE_HOST='IP Server 1', has to be run on server 2 and vice versa. I did the mistake of running it in server 1.
